# I'm trying to get the style of each web browser to look the same

Tags: html, css

This is the problem:

[image: internet explorer]

I'm working on a website and am trying to get both internet browsers to look the same. I posted the stylesheet below.

I'm trying to use css.reset but don't fully understand it. In chrome, the stylesheet creates the website the way I want it to look but in Internet Explorer it does not. The pixels for the picture would be to the opposite direction by about 200 pixels. i'm trying to post a second picture of what explorer looks like as well.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}

html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: white
}


h3 {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:960px){
 /* styles for browsers larger than 960px; */
 .center{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 125px;
  right: 420px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1440px){
 /* styles for browsers larger than 1440px; */

}
@media only screen and (min-width:2000px){
 /* for sumo sized (mac) screens */
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px){
   /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
    .center{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 150px;
  right: 130px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 350px;
  position: fixed
 }
}
@media only screen and (device-width:768px){
   /* default iPad screens */
}
/* different techniques for iPad screening */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts only */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts only */
}

 

/*must aways have a position
 VIDEO SECTION
*/



@media only screen and (min-width:960px){
 /* styles for browsers larger than 960px; */
 video{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 150px;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px){
   /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
 video{
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  bottom: 500px;
 }
}



h4 {
 text-align: center; 
 color: white
}
h2 {
 text-align: center; 
 color: white
}

h5 {
 text-align: center; 
 color: white
}

 
p{
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 top: 400px; 
}




body {
 /*This is the pages background color*/
 background-color: #000080;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 color:white;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tab {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: auto;
 /* tab color*/
 background-color: #cccccc;
 opacity: 1;
}

.boarder {
 float: left;
 border: 2px groove black;
}

ol {
 word-break: break-all;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: decimal;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
 /*This works like an margin in word where it the words 
 a few inches from the border*/
    padding-left: 30px;
}

ol li {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 35px;
}

.boarder_2{
 border: 5px groove black;
 border-style: solid;
 margin: 0;
 opacity: 1;
 border-color: #5791ed; 
 padding: 5px;
}


li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 8px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #111;
}

.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.none {
 float: none;
}

li {
 float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ewnn.png)

Comment: Would you be able to post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? The snippet is a start, but it does not cause any differences between browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not easy, website can show different in different browsers, internet explorer is the worst. Try with deleting

```
 width: 100%;
```

in html css tag, also theres a lot articles about this, read it.

Comment: that actually worked! Thank you, I've been trying to figure that out for weeks.

Comment: No problem, can you flag as answer please

Comment: last question, how do I do that? flag as answered that is.

Comment: You go flag and go as asnwer